# Which one? KVO or Block for viewmodel to notify controller in MVVM?

Tags: ios, mvvm, block, key-value-observing

For example,I have model Person,and a viewmodel PersonViewModel.

PersonViewModel hold Person.Controller hold PersonViewModel;

PersonViewModel provide data for present view,like

```
-(nsstring*)personNameInChinese;
```

but i don't no how to notify controller when the model changed，especially the after the asyc funtion.is `KVO or BLock`?

for example, PersonViewModel has a func :`-(void)refreshPersonInfo;`//it will start a network request

there has two way to choose:
1.set a `refreshCompleteBlock` for `PersonViewModel`,and add refresh view's code in that block,Controller set the block before he call the start refresh func.

2.add a `BOOL` property like 'isRefreshing' for PersonViewModel,add Controller observe the 'isRefreshing',and when it changed,refresh views

Comment: Blocks look cleaner than KVO. The only thing u need to make sure though is not to hold a strong reference to block and pass strong self to block as param in which case u'll end up with both block and self not being released.